# Prevent duplicate form submission registration woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, field, registration

I have a custom fields in my woommerce registration form.
So for prevent duplicate email there is a control just but if I have a custom field I created how can I check it?
thanks

This code is only for check if exist

```
    function wooc_validate_extra_register_fields( $username, $email, $validation_errors ) {

        if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {

             $validation_errors->add( 'billing_first_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: First name is required!', 'woocommerce' ) );

      }

      if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {

             $validation_errors->add( 'billing_last_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Last name is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );

      }
         return $validation_errors;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', 'wooc_validate_extra_register_fields', 10, 3 );
```